# Writing a hiveserver2 query result to CSV with Python using pyhs2

Tags: python, python-2.x, csv, hadoop, hiveql

I am trying to create a small application that will help me extract data from Hadoop via hiveserver2 by simply writing it to CSV. At the moment, it takes about 40 seconds to pull 10,000 records from a hs2 table consisting of 500k rows with 203 columns. I would like to think that there is a faster, more efficient way of doing this than the way I am doing it now. Ideally I would like to eventually be able to pull and write 1 million rows per minute. It doesn't necessarily have to be written to CSV. It probably isn't feasible with my current skill level, but I like to set goals for myself.

```
import pyhs2
import time
import csv

csv_out = open('data.csv', 'wb')
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)

def generic_user():
    gu = 'xxxxxx'
    return gu

def password():
    pw = 'xxxxxxx'
    return pw


with pyhs2.connect(host='xxxxxxxx',
               port=10000,
               authMechanism='PLAIN',
               user=generic_user(),
               password=password(),
               database='xxxxxxxxxx') as conn:

    with conn.cursor() as cur:

        q = raw_input('Enter query: ').replace('csc', 'CSC')
        print q

        #timer start
        start_time = time.time()

        #Execute query
        cur.execute(q)

        col = []

        for key in cur.getSchema():
            col.append(key['columnName'])

        header = []
        header.append(col)

        for rows in zip(header):
            mywriter.writerows(rows)

        records = cur.fetch()
        # print records

        for rows in zip(records):
            mywriter.writerows(rows)

pull_time = time.time() - start_time
print pull_time
```

Answer (score 2):

## Speed improvements

Using a `for` loop to build a list is quite slow, when Python has 'list comprehensions'. They're for loop like expressions that build lists. So your `col` could be changed from this:

```
for key in cur.getSchema():
    col.append(key['columnName'])
```

to this:

```
col = [key['columnName'] for key in cur.getSchema()]
```

As far as I can tell, your header is actually pointless. You're making it just a single item list that then gets iterated over to write to your file. This seems to be the same as just `mywriter.writerows(col)`.

Your use of `zip` is confusing. `zip` is used to join two or more lists when iterating. It's not normally used for a single list like you have, and doesn't really do much for you unless I'm missing something. It's a redundant drain on your time.

## Other notes

You use context managers (`with x as y`) for the connection which is great, but you should do the same for your `csv_out`.

```
with open('data.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
```

It's extra safety for your file the same way you have with the connections.

I'd also recommending refactoring your code into discrete functions rather than just one long script. It's better for readability and debugging purposes. Plus it makes it easier to change or reuse this code later.

Comment: Yes the header part is strange.  The reason for it is because using col iterates each character s,o,,i,t,l,o,o,k,s,,l,i,k,e,,t,h,i,s, for some reason and the easiest way I knew to fix it was to just make another list appending it.

the plan is to eventually break it into discrete functions.  I wanted to get some better performance first.  When I ran cProfile it appears that the majority of the time (72 of the 75 seconds) was spent fetching data.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code loads all results into a list in memory and then writes them to the csv file, rather than writing them to the csv file as it receives them. You might be able to speed up your code by changing this

```
    records = cur.fetch()  ## <--- loads all results at once
    # print records

    for rows in zip(records):
        mywriter.writerows(rows)
```

to this:

```
from itertools import izip

for rows in izip(cur):  ## <--- loads results in chunks as needed
    mywriter.writerows(rows)
```

[`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) returns an iterator rather than a list, so it generates values as needed rather than generating all of them upfront and storing them in memory in a list. (The reason `zip` and `izip` are needed at all is to convert each item in the iterator into a single-element tuple).

Comment: so would this be similar to fetchmany()?

Comment: From having a quick look at the source code (https://github.com/BradRuderman/pyhs2/blob/master/pyhs2/cursor.py#L143), yes I believe so. The difference being that fetchMany() only returns a limited number of results at once, so you would have to call it repeatedly to get all of the results, whereas if you just iterate over the cursor these repeated calls occur but are "hidden" from you.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  izip improved memory use significantly and very marginally, the speed :)